# How to actually change HTML5 localStorage size in browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, html5, local-storage

I'm interested in HTML5's [`localStorage`](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) feature which surprisingly doesn't appear to be all that well documented.

I found [this excellent StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2989317/4009451) about the size limits of `localStorage` per browser. In that answer, the user states:

> ...the size of this storage area can be customized by the user (so a 5MB storage area is not guaranteed, nor is it implied) and the user agent.

So I became curious: how could I tweak `localStorage` settings on my browser (Chrome)? Well I looked high and low. I Googled, Yahooed and Binged. And for the life of me I can't find where `localStorage` can be configured inside Chrome 38.x.

And although I'm specifically interested in Chrome 38.x, I'll happily welcome any answers that show how to do this from any modern-ish browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the answer you are quoting, is missing some key wording, which is

> **if the agent allows it,** the size of this storage area can be customized...

There is some good research on this topic here:   [Working with quota on mobile browsers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/)

It appears that Chrome doesn't have UI to customize the size of your storage, but there is working being done on an [API to request additional storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/quota-api/).

Comment: Thanks @heavyd (+1) - interesting link for the **Quota Management API**... would this be an HTML5/JavaScript API? Thanks again!

Comment: Three years later, there must be some more useful answer to that. I tried to use [that API](http://www.w3.org/TR/quota-api/) and it returns some misleading info: “we are using 0 of **14.85 gigabytes**” for `webkitTemporaryStorage` and “0 gigabytes” for `webkitPersistentStorageage`. My code (try in browser console): `navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage.queryUsageAndQuota((used, granted) => console.log('we are using', used, 'of', granted/1024/1024/1024, 'gigabytes'), e => console.log('Error', e));`